# how to show individual discount applied while chackout?

Tags: magento, show, checkout, discount

I have applied shopping cart rules in my magento store successfully, but in cart when total is calculated it shows directly total discount.

It doesn't show individual discount price applied to which product.

How to show individual discount to let customer know that on which product I got discount?

Answer (score 0):

To get the individual discount amount for each product while checkout, you can do as below :

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item){
    $discount = $item->getDiscountAmount();
// $discount is the discount amount for the individual item
}
```